# Mostrar LinkedHashSet en orden inverso

Tags: java

Quiero imprimir por consola una lista `LinkedHashSet` pero en el orden inverso, es decir al revés, tiene que ser utilizando *iteradores*. Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
 private static void printReverseLinkedList(LinkedHashSet<Examen> orderExam) {
    Iterator<Examen> iterator = orderExam.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.print( iterator.next().toString() );
    }
```

Esto me lo imprime en su orden correcto, no como yo quiero.Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres mantenerte usando iteradores, debes usar una LinkedList. Es una cuestión de lógica matemática, una lista está ordenada mientras que un set es una colección sin orden. Lo que puedes hacer es crear una lista nueva a partir de tu set y luego usar el iterador inverso `descendintIterator()`

```
LinkedList<T> examList = new LinkedList<>(orderExam);
```

Simplemente utiliza `descendintIterator()` en lugar de `Iterator()`.

```
Iterator<Examen> iterator = examList.descendingIterator();
```

De esta forma puedes iterar en orden inverso.

Comment: Hola Mario Gracias por la aportación, pero el método descendintIterator(), no es compatible con la linkedHashSet, o por lo menos me da error de compilación.

Comment: Lei mal la pregunta, leí linkedList no LinkedSet. Ahora actualizo la respuesta pero ya te aviso que no tiene sentido que quieras ordenar un set que, por definición, no tiene orden...

Comment: @Blazerg, LinkedHashSet **sí** tiene orden - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev http://net-informations.com/java/cjava/list.htm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035008/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-list

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev lo que pone en la api de java es que los objetos de la clase LinkedHashSet mantienen el orden en el que han sido insertados pero un set NO es una colección ordenada y, por tanto, no está preparada para operaciones en las que importe el orden como descendintIterator(). Para eso están las listas que, por definición, si son colecciones ordenadas. 
Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias @Blazerg Por la aclaración en tu respuesta.